# Suppose $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are sequences such that $\{x_n\}\to l$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$ suppose $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are sequences such that $\{x_n\}\to l$ and for all n, $y_n=x_{n+k}$ .prove that $\{y_n\}\to l$

*my work:*

given $\{x_n\}$ is converges to l

then there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N,|x_n-l|<\epsilon$

since give  $k\in \mathbb{N}$ this also true  $n+k>N,|x_{n+k}-l|<\epsilon$

And hence $\{y_n\}\to l$

Comment: Yes, it's that simple.

Comment: Well done..your prood is  fine.